# no terminal output in VSCODE in python3

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I haved defined a function to check PIG LATIN 
function runs on anaconda navigator but no terminal output in vs code.

```
def pig_latin(word):

    first_letter = word[0]

    if first_letter in 'aeiou':
        pig_word = word + 'ay'
    else:
        pig_word =  word[1:] + first_letter + 'ay'  
    return pig_word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output in the terminal, you have to call the `print()` function.
At the last line of your code, call the `pig_latin` function with `print()` function, something like:

```
def pig_latin(word):

    first_letter = word[0]

    if first_letter in 'aeiou':
        pig_word = word + 'ay'
    else:
        pig_word =  word[1:] + first_letter + 'ay'  
    return pig_word
print(pig_latin('hello'))
```

If you're using Python 2.x, you can print to console by calling print without the parentheses:
`print pig_latin('hello')`

And make sure that the file is saved with a *.py* extension and run it by calling `python3 fileName.py`

Comment: Thank you , but still there is no output.

Comment: What are you getting in terminal? Any error or anything? Or nothing at all?

Comment: What do you mean command tab? So you are getting the prompt for next command without any output from the previous run?

Comment: the same one..in the next line of terminal.. siri@DESKTOP-MINGW32 ~/Desktop
$

Comment: its window @DavidCullen

Comment: Are you in the correct directory, i.e. where your file is saved? Is your file saved on Desktop or in some folder? You have to run the command from where your file is.

Comment: yes i am  in correct directory. file is saved on Desktop and i  m  running the command from Desktop.

Comment: Can you please update the entire script that you have and also it's location and how you are running it.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma If you have got it working, please upvote and mark the answer as 'Accepted answer'. Thanks.